# Postgres: REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW CONCURRENTLY not actually refreshing the view

Tags: python, postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

Postgres: REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW CONCURRENTLY not actually refreshing the view.

The company I work for has a heavy reliance on materialized views for metrics and reporting. Because of this we have a service that runs in AWS fargate that essentially attempts to run "REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW CONCURRENTLY {view} WITH DATA" on each view daily.

We have always had issues with views not staying up to date, in which case we would just go into pgadmin and (using the GUI) run the refresh on the view. Recently I have been looking into this , as it seemed that the logs (for our refresh service) showed the view being successfully refreshed, however the data would be out dated (sometimes weeks of missing data). But when I run the same refresh manually, the data is up to date in the view.

I have completed the following troubleshooting/investigative steps:

- verified that the queries being executed in the service are actually executing on the production writer instance of the database in AWS RDS.
- Verified that the connection to the database in the service is correct.
- Verified that we have RDS metrics of the queries executing.
- Verified that we do not have duplicate views in other schemas.
- Performed experiment where I waited for the refresh from our refresh service to finish executing , immediately checked the table, verified that the data was out of date and that there were no concurrent queries against the table locking it , then ran a manual refresh and verified that the data was correctly up to date after that.
- verified that the service is auto committing after each refresh.

--example--

```
 print("Creating database engine")

    engine = create_engine(DATABASE_URL)
    engine = engine.execution_options(autocommit=True)


    def refresh_material(view_name):
        query = f"REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW CONCURRENTLY {view_name} WITH DATA"
        
        with engine.connect() as connection:
            result = connection.execute(text(query))
          
            return result
```

I am at a lose on what could be causing this. Any one have any ideas or advice on how to troubleshoot this?

Comment: The `autocommit=True` notwithstanding it looks to me like the command is being rolled back on connection close. Try without the `autocommit` and then after `connection.execute(text(query))` do `connection.commit()`.